# Error in Groovy Regex matching. What does this error signify?

Tags: regex, groovy

This is the error I see.

> Problem in JSR223 script, ABC
>   javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.regex.Matcher) values: [callbackUri, java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=(?<=callbackUri=).*(?=&) region=0,537 lastmatch=]]
>   Possible solutions: put(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), get(java.lang.String), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), wait(), any(), dump()

This is the line that is causing it:

```
def callbackUriMatch = (redirectQuery =~ /(?<=callbackUri=).*(?=&)/)[0]
```

Comment: No, that is not the relevant line. The error message is ` No signature of method: 
 org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.regex.Matcher)`. You will need to pass two `String`s or a `String` and an `Object`. Your `callbackUriMatch` seems to be a `java.util.regex.Matcher`.

Comment: It just means you have no match and there is no item with index 0. Check for a match first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not find a match and the Matcher Group 0 is not initialized. You need to use a safer regex and always check if there is a match before trying to access any group:

```
def redirectQuery = "&callbackUri=someValue"
def callbackUriMatch = redirectQuery =~ /(?<=[&?]callbackUri=)[^&]*/
if (callbackUriMatch) {
    println callbackUriMatch.group()
}
```

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/NI7m2P)

Here, `callbackUriMatch` is a `java.util.regex.Matcher` object. With `if (callbackUriMatch)`, a check if the match is found is performed, and if there is a match, you can access `callbackUriMatch.group()`, the whole match.

**Pattern details**

- `(?<=[&?]callbackUri=)` - as you want to get a query param value, it should be preceded with `&` or `?`, then match your key value and `=`, and this pattern is wrapped with a lookbehind construct that does not add its matched text to the match value
- `[^&]*` - a negated character class matching 0 or more chars other than `&`.